# find the path of jdk and set JAVAHOME

Tags: ubuntu, java

I've got java installed on my Ubuntu VirtualBox, and I am trying to run sunspot, but sunspot can't find java.

typing 'java' from the command line return

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * gcj-4.4-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

and everything I've seen says that java should be in '/usr/lib/jdk', but I don't have '/usr/lib/jdk' in my directory.

How can I:

1. Find the install for openjdk-7-jre-headless
2. sudo export home, as I've had problems in the past setting the export home, without proper access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by your questions, but...

*Find the install for openjdk-7-jre-headless*

You can do this by using `apt-get` at the command line:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

Follow the prompts and it'll install this package and everything it needs.

*sudo export home, as I've had problems in the past setting the export home, without proper access*

If you execute the command `sudo export home`, it does nothing - and wouldn't work. `export` is a shell internal command, and `sudo` requires a binary. Even if you made that command work through shell trickery, you'd just set the variable (which should be `JAVA_HOME`) in a new shell then forgets it when the command is done.

You might need to run `java` as root, but I wouldn't do that either: fix the permissions on the files and executables, and don't run as root as this will open your system up to hackers and miscreants.

Comment: I've already installed jdk (or atleast I think i did, I tried to), and when I type `java` into the command line, I thought it would say `not found` if I didn't have it installed.

Comment: you were right david, apparently jdk wasn't installed (or atleast I've done it again.

Comment: What you were seeing (instead of just `command not found`) is part of an Ubuntu package called (appropriately) `command-not-found`. It's not necessary; the added delay while it searches the database drives me up a wall. I usually remove it: `apt-get remove command-not-found command-not-found-data`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make sure you have a java package installed using:

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep jre
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep jdk
```

From the error you got after typing java, I think java is not installed.

Also, you can use `which java` to search for the binary java in your path. To export the java, you can for example use:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/java/home
```

Comment: Thanks Khaled, the `sudo dpgk` and `which java` commands don't return anything, so I'm not sure what that means. It didn't return the path to my java. If java was not installed, I thought I would get a 'not found' error when typing `java` at the command line.

Comment: It seems that you don't have java installed. You can try to install it using `apt-get install`.